# MDS Matrix Elements

Tags: aes, mds

Can zero be one of the elements used in an MDS matrix (in the context of AES)?

Based on what I have read all entries of an MDS Matrix need to be non-zero. Also, I would appreciate any help in understanding the reason behind this requirement if zero cannot be an element of MDS.

Comment: In any MDS matrix, any square submatrix (subset of rows/columns) must be invertible. This includes 1x1 matrices.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, for MDS codes used in the way it is used in AES there's no other choice, i.e., an MDS code with these dimension must have all entries nonzero in the $M$ matrix.

The MDS matrix $M$ has to be square, mapping 4 bytes to 4 bytes and must have 4 nonzero entries in each row by MDS property.

It also means changing each input byte affects each output byte, helping in diffusion.

*Background:* by coding theory the code is generated by the $k\times n$ matrix $$G=[I|M]$$
The Matrix converts a length $k$ message $m$ to the codeword $c$ via
$$
c=mG
$$
where $m,c$ are row vectors. This code has minimum weight $n-k+1$, the maximum possible by singleton bound. Since each row is a codeword the $M$ submatrix must have rows of minimum weight $n-k$. For AES, $n=2k=8$ so $n-k=4.$ So the rows of $M$ must have 4 nonzero entries.

Comment: Thank you @kodlu, really appreciate your help.

Comment: ok, you can upvote the answer :-)

Comment: I tried doing that but the platform does not allow me unfortunately. Here is the message I keep getting: "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."

Comment: @kodlu what do you mean by "no other choice"?

Comment: @kodlu could you take the advantage of the title to write this answer for beginners?

Comment: @kodlu Does not MDS matrix have any application in crypto. Any references or applications are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

After digging deeper here is what I found:

> Let M be an MDS matrix, for **any square sub-matrix** Mi,j of M. From the property of MDS matrices, every sub-matrix should be non-singular.

> No Mi,j elements belonging to M can be equal to zero, since this would lead to a singular submatrix of type 1×1 in M and thus would contradict the non-singularity requirement.

Simply put the cofactor matrix cannot be zero for a 1x1 sub-matrix of M if M is MDS since every sub-matrix of M should be non-singular (invertible).

https://www.aimsciences.org/article/doi/10.3934/amc.2019045