# regarding MDS matrix and security

Tags: hash, mds

I found a construction for MDS matrix (algorithm 4 of https://eprint.iacr.org/2020/1143) for a hash function that compresses elements in a prime field $F_p$

If the hash has a rate and capacity $(r,c)$ and $m = r+c$. It proceeds as

1. Identify a primitive root of unity $g$ in $F_p$.
2. Write a Vandermonde Matrix $V[i,j] = g^{ij}$ where $ i=0,1,\ldots m-1$ and $j=0,1,\ldots 2m$
3. Reduce it to a row echelon form
4. Then $V = I|M^T$ where $I_{m\times m}$ is unit matrix and $M$ is the desired MDS matrix.

The security level offered by the hash $s= \log_2(\sqrt{p})min(r,c)$. I wanted to know if the MDS construction in this form is independent of the security level.

The above resource is from the rescue hash function, that provides $122$ bit security, with $p = 2^{61}+20.2^{32}+1$ and $r=8, c=4$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally MDS matrices are chosen because of their mixing properties see, e.g., [this question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/85920/mds-matrix-elements/85931#85931) and those properties hold for any MDS matrix. So I would say that the choice  of the specific MDS matrix is independent of the security level.

In the document you linked to the authors say, on page 12:

> There are cases where better performance is afforded by optimizing the MDS
> with respect to some design criterion. Section 2.4 specifies Vandermonde matrices as the standard way to generate the MDS matrix. However the original
> publication did not limit the choice of MDS to any specific type and argues
> its security with respect to any MDS matrix. The decision to be more restrictive merely simplifies the standard specification and is not known to have any
> security implications for algorithms following the Marvellous design strategy.

> **Choosing the MDS matrix:** any MDS matrix can be used.
> The number of rounds is unaffected by this decision.
> Selection the Round Constants is unaffected by this decision.

> **Confidence Level** is high. This variant was explicitly covered in the generic
> security argument of the original publication

Comment: Thanks a lot! I missed it.