# Can we change the irreducible polynomial of AES algorithm?

Tags: encryption, aes

The `AES algorithm` uses the irreducible polynomial. Consider

```
x^8+x^4+x^3+x+1
```

for multiplying with a [MDS matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MDS_matrix) for encryption and decryption. Am I allowed to change this polynomial with another one? If so, then I need to redesign the MDS matrix? Does this effect security standards?

Comment: Note that, you can change it for research purposes - any result you obtain are not compatible with real-world AES/Rijndael, and won't pass conformance tests.

Answer (score 4):

Any MDS matrix would have the same security properties.

See this related answer:

[regarding MDS matrix and security](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/100369/regarding-mds-matrix-and-security/100372#100372)

This specific irreducible polynomial has to do with the choice of the specific finite field $GF(2^8)$ representation for scalar operations and has been chosen due to its efficiency properties with respect to arithmetic operations. It is independent of the choice of the MDS matrix.

Comment: Will dig into that!